# UITableView over UICollectionView touch handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have an application that requires to have in one screen an `**UICollectionView**` that will display images horizontally and a UITableView that will come from the bottom when a button is pressed or when I slide up on the second half of the screen (bottom area). When the table view is fully revealed it will cover the bottom half of the screen and the UICollectionView with images will still be visible in the top half of the screen. For accomplishing this the table view will have a transparent header view that will cover the bottom half of the screen so the collection view will be fully visible. When dragging upwards on the transparent header the cells of the table view will become visible.

The problem is I have to be able to scroll the `**UICollectionView**` horizontally when the header view of the table it's on the bottom half of the screen but same time be able to scroll in the table.

The view hierarchy contains first the `**UICollectionView**` and then the `**UITableView**`.

There is any possibility to do this in a clean way without jumping in many UX problems?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: adding a screenshot whould be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: You may not need any transparent header view, gesture recognizer with just one direction and detect touch point in collection view should also do the job.

Comment: Do you want to have a constant/fixed CollectionView which will be visible all the time irrespective of the TableView scroll ?

Comment: I've posted two images with state 1 of the screen and state 2 of the screen. This is the behavior I am pursuing. For the moment I have an UICollectionView and a UIScrollView that changes its frame when "Plus d'info" button is pressed. But I need to be able to reveal the bottom view with slide gesture too and be responsive on the entire path of the gesture (like a table view it's behaving).

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding two UIView in one view controller and try your UICollectionView and Also UITable view.